# Handling SQL comparison operators in express GET routes - Filtering

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

I'm having struggle to use SQL comparison operators in express GET routes.

I know that, with MongoDB (using Mongoose), we can GET a route like so :

```
app.get('/users?age[gte]=20', …)
```

Which we can then handle like so in our controller function :

```
// Get the query parameters from the GET URL :
const queryObj = { ...req.query };

let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);

// Modify the comparison operators passed in the query (add the $ sign) :
queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, match => `$${match}`);

console.log(JSON.parse(queryStr)); // Returns { age: { '$gte': '20' } }

// With the above example - GET /users?age[gte]=20 -, we can then use it directly to fetch users with age >= 20 :
const users = await Users.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

However, how can I do this for SQL comparison operators, using Knex ? As we don't want them to be nested in the query string object.

I tried different REGEX to get >=, >, <, <=, instead of the Mongoose ones ($gte, $gt,…), the problem is that, with the brackets in the query string, I get something like this :

```
queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\bgte\b/g, '>=');

console.log(JSON.parse(queryStr)); // Returns { age: { '>=': '20' } }
```

Because I use Knex, as far as I know, I can not directly use this kind of object in the query, as I did with Mongoose.

What is the best way to deal with this and "automate" the filtering function like I did with the Mongoose example ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry to appear non-helpful, but learning how to write SQL queries will help a long way. There is no robust way to write code for SQL databases without understanding how they work. The best way to take your approach is to write helper function which takes mongoose-like input object and returns a query builder with equivalent filters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I work mostly on SQL databases and have no problem writing complexe raw SQL queries, without Knex. I asked this because, while learning more noSQL, I found this way to kind of easily "automate" the filtering queries (using this "universal syntax" style in a simple class) and guessed that there should be a way to do the same with Knex. But I guess you're right. Since then, I did what you said : using helper functions to build my query filter strings. But it doesn't have this "universal syntax" style that I can easily use in a simple class along with Knex